# How do I programatically lay tiles with the Godot engine?

Tags: procedural-generation, godot

I am completely new to Godot Engine, and quite an amateur in game development, in general. I have a small project where I want to implement a procedurally generated level, and for that I'd like to be able to programmatically place tiles. I'm thinking about something like in [this video for GameMaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZtMNnXFnHE&t=170s), however, I haven't found a documented way to do that for Godot.

Does Godot support programmatically laying tiles, and if so, how?

Answer (score 14):

You can programmatically set a cell in the [`TileMap`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_tilemap.html) class by using the [`set_cell`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_tilemap.html#class-tilemap-method-set-cell) function.

Note: if you're new to an engine & game dev in general, I highly recommend working through any of the tutorial information provided; I happened to come across the the link to the `TileMap` class in:

2d Tutorials -> Graphics -> [Using TileMaps](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/2d/using_tilemaps.html)

Note: the above was for the 3.x version of Godot. 
Information for the  current/stable version can be found [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/using_tilemaps.html) or by changing the version in the lower left hand corner:

[image: screenshot drawing attention to version]

Comment: @Case Thanks for pointing that out. I answered for an older version - looks like some of the links transitioned to the newer version & some didn't. Should be fixed now w/ options to get to either.

Comment: No problem, maybe you could help me with my question, since you seem to be quite knowledgeable on Godot. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/208264/godot-4-isometric-snap-grid