# Godot 4 - Isometric Snap Grid

Tags: tilemap, godot, isometric

While there is rotation in the snap grid settings it does not seem to be rotating the displayed grid.  I can use a Isometric tilemap, but without a grid displayed at all times, I cannot perfect Collision boxes over said tilemap. I am only working in 2D, so I am hoping this exists, or perhaps where to edit the C itself in order to add the functionality.